dplyr: count unique values
I have a data:
df <- data.frame(strain = 1:6, sample = c("a24", "a24", "a24", "a26", "a26", "a27"), region = c(rep("ny", 3), rep("detroit",3)))

I want to count the number of sample per region and get something like:



region
sample_count




ny
1


detroit
2



I.e. ny has only one sample "a24", and detroit has two samples "a26" and "a27"

count(df, region, sample) |> count(region, name="sample_count")

this way:
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  group_by(region) |> 
  summarise(sample_count = n_distinct(sample))

Output is:
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  region  sample_count
  <chr>          <int>
1 detroit            2
2 ny                 1

